# How to fix turtlebot3_bringup is not a launch file name?

Tags: ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm trying to run

```
roslaunch turtlebo3_bringup
```

but it doesn't seem to work. The error I get is:

```
[turtlebot3_bringup] is not a launch file name
```

The traceback for the exception was written to the log file

Please help, Thank you!!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/311026/how-to-fix-turtlebot3_bringup-is-not-a-launch-file-name?/) by [turtlebot3](https://answers.ros.org/users/37964/turtlebot3/) on ROS Answers with karma: 42 on 2018-12-18

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) on 2018-12-18**:
Can you please update your question with the entire command that you're running?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You haven't specified *which* launch file you're trying to launch, but I looked the [GitHub repo](https://github.com/ROBOTIS-GIT/turtlebot3/tree/master/turtlebot3_bringup) and there doesn't appear to be a `turtlebot3_bringup` launch file. So, if you're trying to use the `turtlebot3_robot.launch` launch file use the following command

```
roslaunch turtlebot3_bringup turtlebot3_robot.launch
```

The pattern for using launch files is

```
roslaunch <package-name> <launch-file>
```

and then you can use some args. See the [roslaunch wiki](https://wiki.ros.org/roslaunch) for more information.

---

Originally posted by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) with karma: 6155 on 2018-12-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [turtlebot3](https://answers.ros.org/users/37964/turtlebot3/) on 2018-12-18**:
Thank you so much, I guess i forgot to add the turtlebot3_robot.launch